# Import-Excel converting column to scientific notation and corrupting value

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, import-from-excel

I am trying to automate the importing of a county file and convert it to csv. The issue I am having is that the account number is getting converted to scientific notation.

```
Import-Excel BacktaxRaw_FL_Flagler2.xlsx | Export-Csv ExportTest.csv
```

If I tried formatting number fields to be text fields using

```
C:\testdata> Import-Excel BacktaxRaw_FL_Flagler.xlsx | Export-Excel ExportTest.xlsx -Show -AutoSize -NumberFormat '@'
```

The problem here is that the account number last few digits are replaced with Zero. Example. The original number is ''1914310000010100016", Import is converting it to "1.9143100000101E+18 and finally the export is getting converted to "1914310000010100000". As you can see the 16 at the end is replaced with 00.

Ironically if I import the data into a new excel file and specify importing the data through excel and define the type as text then I can use Import-excel to convert to csv with no issue. This is telling me that Import-Excel is struggling to import the data from the original excel file. Can someone help me with this issue please?

I have attached the import file:
[BacktaxRaw_FL_Flagler.xlsx](https://www.lumentumllc.us/BacktaxRaw_FL_Flagler.xlsx)

After doing some research and thanks to Ron's suggestions, I did a deeper dive to view the raw source code of the above file. I unzipped the contents of the BacktaxRaw_FL_Flagler.xlsx file and navigated to the \xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml file. I opened in notepad and saw first hand that none of the values I am looking for in column A are stored in scientific notation. They are in deed stored uncorrupted. Which means every attempt I have made to retrieve the data has resulted in data corruption. Even using Excels own data import wizard will alter the values.

[Screen shot](https://www.screencast.com/t/kJ2iHWuIFov) So you don't need to download file

If you want, download the raw xml file here:
[Raw XML file](https://www.lumentumllc.us/sheet1.xml)

Comment: I'm confused. Which is the original file (excel or CSV), and what is the desired result?.  If CSV is the original, you need to tell Excel that the data it is importing is **Text**.  If the Excel is the original, then the data in your linked file already has the error you are trying to avoid.

Comment: The Excel file is the original file. I am trying any which way to convert to csv. The real problem is that in the original excel file there is a column called "Account Number" that has a value of ''1914310000010100016". Now matter what method I use to convert (programmatically that is) the end result is a csv file that either has "1.9143100000101E+18" or "1914310000010100000". Notice that the last two digits are replaced with 00. End result when I convert to CSV, the value ''1914310000010100016" should remain ''1914310000010100016". While I would like to use Import-Excel I will use anything.

Comment: In the file you attached, I do not see **any** values like `1914310000010100016`.  The numeric values in the Account Number column have already been converted to their numeric values.  See Rows 3,23,25,28,30 and higher.

Comment: If you open directly in excel without doing anything you will see 1.91431E+18 (A3). [Original File Screen Shot](https://www.screencast.com/t/XgfscAS6iY) If you use Excels data import wizard and set column A as text you will see the correct values.  [Fixed File Screen Shot](https://www.screencast.com/t/VcDqm8BdKF9). But when I import using Import-Excel I get a corrupted value [Converted File Screen Shot](https://www.screencast.com/t/5IniBauVfUa).

Comment: Yes, but when you "*use Excels data import wizard*", where are you importing it from???

Comment: From the file I uploaded. It does not appear as if the original file has the correct value, but it does. Check out this [video](https://www.screencast.com/t/G6uncJ5SEz0). In it I am only working on one file, the file I uploaded in my original question. In the first part of the video I am opening the file directly by opening excel. When I do, you will see the scientific notation version and then the corrupted version when I change the format. In the second part I use the Import Data Wizard, where I import the same file. Here I transform to text and you can see the correct value.

Comment: I do not believe that is a valid conversion.  Have you verified the validity of the account numbers?  For example, if I save an `.xlsx` file with a value of `1914310000010100000` in some cell, it will be stored in the file as `1.9143100000101E+18`.  If I then run through the same process you show in your video, using `Power Query` and import, it will be converted to `1914310000010099968`. Clearly different from the entered and the stored values. I think the issue is that the Excel file you are using as a source was generated improperly.

Comment: Also, examing the xml of your original file, it appears that the value stored in `A3` is also `1.9143100000101E+18` and not `1914310000010100016`, again indicating an incorrect conversion by the import process.

Comment: You gave me a lot to think about. I never considered that the county is providing a corrupt file. I did more digging. [Report Online](https://www.screencast.com/t/9V6aJnFjg5). I downloaded the csv version and validated that yes `1914310000010100016` is correct. But your not wrong either. After inspecting other records I found other accounts not converted correctly. [Comparison](https://www.screencast.com/t/0O3EkLwwZ5). Based on this I think you are correct. The original file has the scientific notation stored and not the correct value. It was just luck that excel got the first one right.

Comment: Nope, sorry to say I can now say with out a shadow of a doubt that the correct (non corrupted) value is correctly stored in the xlsx file. [Actual XML of sheet1](https://www.screencast.com/t/kJ2iHWuIFov). I unziped the xlsx file and I navigated to xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml. I opened the file in notepad (to ensure nothing got formatted). After inspection, none of the values are stored as scientific notation and none of them are incorrect. Which basically means no matter how you open the excel file, Excel itself will corrupt the data.

Comment: Ron, after years of Importing Data using the import data wizard, you have proven to me it is not reliable either. Thank you Microsoft! Which brings me back to my original question how can I programmatically import an excel file with out corrupting the data.

Comment: Looking at the link you provided in the screenshot you shared at ReportOnline, I see there is an option to download a CSV file.  If you do that, you'll be able to import into Excel with no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior seems odd.  Especially since an Excel cell that is stored as a text string will retain that property if just opened in Excel.

So I delved into the Open Office XML specifications a bit more closely.

Examining the XML of the document closely, it appears that the document was created incorrectly.  I suspect the xlsx workbook was NOT created by Excel, but rather by some other program.

If I am correct, for the cell in question **A3**, the value is stored as a number and formatted as General.

```
<c r="A3" s="2"><v>1914310000010100016</v></c>
```

`s="2"` points to a General format in the style table, and the value is stored directly.

If it were stored as a string, with a format of text, the entry would look something like:

`r="A3" s="1" t="s"><v>10247</v></c>`

where `t="s"` represents a value from a string table -- actually the 10247th (0-based counting) entry from the SharedStrings table which doesn't even exist in your original xlsx, but will be created if you format A3 as text, then enter the account number for that entry, and then save the file.

So rather than a problem with the import process, I am thinking there is a problem with the actual xlsx file creation.  And that we have no control over.

If the file creation problem cannot be corrected, you will need a non-Excel tool that can edit the XML files to correct the problem.

**Note:** If the county can provide a CSV file, instead of an improperly created Excel file, you should be able to import that without difficulty.
**Note:** I see that one of the options on the page is to download a CSV file. Just use that option and then you'll be able to import with no issues at all!

Comment: Yes the counties offer csv as an option but one of the reason we stopped processing csv files is because recently the csv files are not being formatted correctly either. Text columns are not being correctly quoted, so commas within the file are messing up imports. For this county, the file was formatted correctly but not true for all counties. In this case the excel file is better but I am facing corrupt value issues with excel. Rock and hard place situation. I would love to go back to csv but there is no fix to bad formatted csv. I hope there is a work around for excel.

Comment: I think you need to speak with your County IT department.

Comment: I should also point out that Import-Excel powershell module does not require an excel installation nor does it use an excel object. This is why I am hopeful that this library has a way to parse the excel file and ignore formatting instructions. Just grab the value as it exists in the xml.

Comment: Perhaps posting a more focused question on how to edit the XML underlying the Excel file, will garner an useful response. Include the information about the CSV file problems, and what we see in the XLM in your question.  I'll take a look at the `import-Excel` module.

Comment: @D1gitalDR Why not just do it in Excel using Power Query?  You have shown that PQ can import the file, and if you specify the `Account Number` column as text, it will return the correct account number.  Then all you have to do is save that worksheet as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Importing csv in Excel can drive you nuts sometimes..

Best thing to do is download the original CSV file and make adjustments in there before opening in Excel.

The trick is to make Excel interpret the values for the "Account Number" column as **strings** instead of numeric values.
This can be done by prefixing all values in that column with a Tab character ("`t").

```
$csvFileIn  = 'D:\Test\Report.csv'
$csvFileOut = 'D:\Test\CorrectedReport.csv'
$ColumnName = 'Account Number'

# import the csv file you have downloaded and format the "Account Number"
# column by prefixing the values with a TAB character ("`t").
# this will effectively force Excel NOT to interpret the value as numeric.
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $csvFileIn
foreach ($item in $csv) { $item.$ColumnName = "`t" + $item.$ColumnName }

# save the updated csv file
# the '-UseCulture' switch makes sure the delimiter used is the same that Excel will use on the same system
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $csvFileOut -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Now you can simply double-click the 'D:\Test\CorrectedReport.csv' file to open in Excel and this should be what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: He's aware of all that. The problem, apparently, is that the County is supplying him with, what I think is, an improperly created Excel file.  And I have not been able to figure out how to create those errors with native Excel tools, so I am thinking they created the file with a non-Excel tool.  Hopefully the database they are using has the capability to export as CSV; or they can fix the Excel export process.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The OP comments _"I downloaded the csv version"_, so it is possible to get a csv file instead of excel. Besides.. what makes you think that _he's aware of all that_? Please let D1gitalDR decide.

Comment: Thanks Theo for your response. csv is an option but unfortunately, as of late, the produced county csv files are also corrupt because they do not quote there text columns and column values now have commas with them. Example, receipt column has a list of receipt numbers separated by commas for one column. This is causing column shifting in csv imports. Excel file is well structure, only problem here is bad excel structure that Ron pointed out. I am hopeful that there is a way to parse the excel file because the data is there, just need to ignore data type instruction in file.